# how to make computed re-evaluate when dynamic

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I created a model that encapsulates filtering logic that I use on a lot of models but I'm having an issue were the `isFiltering` and `clearFilterImg`  computed's only fire once because I'm dynamically evaluating each observable on the model in the `isFiltering` computed.

Is there a way to get these computed's to re-evaluate even though I'm doing dynamic checking? Super secret internal Knockout API call or rewriting the computed in a different way perhaps..?

```
var filterModel = (function () {

    function filterModel(parent) {
        var self = this;

        // needed for the "this" argument when calling the callback
        self.parent = parent;
        // this allows us to clear the filters and only kick off one ajax call regardless of how many filters are cleared at one time
        self.filterThrottle = ko.observable().extend({ throttle: 50 });

        // not firing more than once because the observable properties are checked dynamically
        self.isFiltering = ko.computed(function () {
            console.log("isFiltering called");
            var isFiltering = false;

            for (var property in self) {
                if (self.hasOwnProperty(property) && ko.isObservable(self[property]) && !ko.isComputed(self[property])) {
                    if (self[property]()) { // dynamic property check
                        isFiltering = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return isFiltering;
        });

        // not firing more than once 
        self.clearFilterImg = ko.computed(function () {
            console.log("clearFilterImg called");
            if (self.isFiltering())
                return "/content/images/clear-filter.png";
            else
                return "/content/images/clear-filter-disabled.png";
        });
    }

    filterModel.prototype.clearFilters = function () {
        var self = this;
        for (var property in self) {
            if (self.hasOwnProperty(property) && ko.isObservable(self[property]) && !ko.isComputed(self[property])) {
                // only reset a property if it has a value
                if (self[property]()) {
                    self.filterThrottle(externalbyte.createUUID());
                    self[property](null);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    filterModel.prototype.subscribeToFilters = function (callback) {
        var self = this;
        // fires the callback that makes the ajax call
        self.filterThrottle.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            callback.call(self.parent, true);
        });

        // subscribe to all observables
        for (var property in self) {
            if (self.hasOwnProperty(property) && ko.isObservable(self[property]) && !ko.isComputed(self[property])) {
                self[property].subscribe(function (newValue) {
                    // update the throttling observable to a new random UUID when a filter changes
                    self.filterThrottle(createUUID());
                });
            }
        }
    };

    filterModel.prototype.createFilterObject = function (filter) {
        var self = this;
        for (var property in self) {
            if (self.hasOwnProperty(property) && ko.isObservable(self[property]) && !ko.isComputed(self[property])) {
                filter[property] = self[property]();
            }
        }
        return filter;
    };

    return filterModel;
})();
```

usage:

```
function errorLogListModel() {
    var self = this;
    // create a new filter model
    self.filters = new filterModel(self);
    // add whatever filters I want
    self.filters.errorLogId = ko.observable();
    self.filters.userId = ko.observable();
    self.filters.userName = ko.observable();
    self.getErrors = function(resetPage)
    {
        // make an ajax call to filter records
    };
    // subscribe to any filter changes and call getErrors method
    self.filters.subscribeToFilters(self.getErrors);
}
```

Comment: It does not matter if you are retrieving the value of the observable using `self.myProperty()` or `self['myProperty']()` (the latter is your case). When knockout evaluates the computed function it will register dependencies to the observables you read. So your problem is something else than you believe it is. Could you make a repro of your problem in a jsfiddle or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an isolated sample in jsfiddle I found the fix which is to set `deferEvaluation` to true for the computed's in question.

```
self.isFiltering = ko.computed(function () {
    var isFiltering = false;

    for (var property in self) {
        if (self.hasOwnProperty(property) && ko.isObservable(self[property]) && !ko.isComputed(self[property])) {
            if (self[property]()) {
                isFiltering = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isFiltering;
}, self, { deferEvaluation: true }); // defer evaluation until the model is fully realized
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/rrkh66ha/27/